# PHP nonblocking sockets

Tags: php, sockets, nonblocking

How do you wait for data when using nonblocking sockets in PHP?

Everything works fine up until I need to read data from the socket, that's where I need to properly wait for the data. I'm not exactly sure on how I would check if data is there to be read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If PHP has nonblocking sockets, it should have select.

[socket_select](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php) looks like the right thing to use.

Comment: Ahh, yeah. Totally forgot about that method. That's what I needed. Thank you.